# How to run Maven unit test (testng) on Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have a Maven project and I have included some unit tests. I can run those unit tests from command line using

```
mvn test -Dtest=AppTest
```

It will run the unit test (AppTest class) without any problems. But if I tried to run the test on Eclipse as JUnitTest, I got an error saying

```
"No Tests found with test runner 'JUnit 3'"
```

I know the test (AppTest) is not a JUnit test but I didn't see "maven" option if I right clicked on the test class.

Do you know how I could run the tests on Eclipse?

Comment: The topic is discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451808/running-junit-tests-with-maven-under-eclipse You'll need JUnit 4 dependency in your POM.

Comment: What are you using JUnit3, Junit4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those are testng tests, then you can download the eclipse plugin for TestNG and right click and run them as test class.  Testng plugin [here](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html)

If you want to run the command line way of maven, you would need the maven plugin for eclipse from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases)
Then you can right click your project and you should see an option of Run As -> Maven Test.  You would need to set relevant arguments in the surefire plugin of pom or use run configuration to specify parameters like you did in -Dtest

I would suggest the testng plugin which would be simpler to just select the class and run the class or a single case or a package even.